# Android: best practice!

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать такую задачу:

1. Пользователь прошел авторизацию в приложении и попал на главную активити
2. При создании главное активити с сервера грузятся данные
3. Если пользователь повернул устройство, то при перестроении активити данные начинают грузиться заново

Как избежать повторной загрузки данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

грузить данные не в активити, а в сервисе.

Answer (score 0):

В AndroidManifest.xml в тег активити добавь

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
```

Comment: Какое результат это должно принести? В офф документации ничего не сказано про перестроение активити

Comment: @ua6xh активити перестанет пересоздаваться каждый раз при повороте устройства.

Comment: полностью согласен с @katso

Answer (score 0):

грузи в отдельном от UI потоке - AsyncTask.
Запустишь прогрессдиалог на время загрузки - что бы пользователь никуда не ушел. загрузишь данные - убрал прогрессдиалог и вывел нужную инфу.
У AsyncTask - есть три основных метода доВыполнения,послеВыполнения, и сам процесс выполнения.